# loops break after it hits a certain repetition

Tags: python

I cant seem to figure out what am I doing wrong. Very new to python so maybe making some ignorant mistake

I am trying to print a statement after an interval. The scope is the user would have the ability to print the notification at a set time interval. Right now I have them hard coded

Here is how my code looks like

```
from datetime import datetime

def main():

    initial_time = datetime.now().replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0)

    class add_tm(object): #dynamic time adjustment
        x = 0 ## This will be a user input
        y = 1 ## This will be a user input
        z = 5 ## This will be a user input

    while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        if now > initial_time:
            print("Hello world")
            initial_time = now.replace(hour = now.hour + add_tm.x, minute = now.minute + add_tm.y, second = now.second + add_tm.z, microsecond = 0)

main()
```

The problem is the program stops executing after 5th loop. When it hits the 6th I get a statement
initial_time = now.replace(hour = now.hour + add_tm.x, minute = now.minute + add_tm.y, second = now.second + add_tm.z, microsecond = 0)
ValueError: minute must be in 0..59

I am not able to understand why I am getting this. I mean I somewhat get what it is saying but have no clue what is causing it to say that

Answer (score 5):

`minute = now.minute + add_tm.y`

clearly results in a value less than zero or greater than 59

it has no idea what to do with a minute value outside the range of 0 to 59

try

```
print(now.minute + add_tm.y)
```

to see the value that breaks it

Comment: @joran--Totally get it. But could there be a work around to achieve the expectation?